# Edit .cs files and aspx files using my custom editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing my own asp .net editor to produce and edit Visual studio solutions. So i am trying to open for example a .aspx page in text mode. For now I am trying to get the text with the following code using jQuery but it does not working. Here is my code

```
  jQuery.get('http://localhost:27487/TestSolution/Form1.cs', function (data) {
            alert(data);
```

To the above code if i change Form1.cs and put a text file test.txt that is in the TestSolution folder the alert shows the data of the text file. Any Suggestions or help on how to read .aspx and .cs text in my variable?. Feel free to advice me please.

Comment: Are you building a web application to edit source code? `.cs` is a blocked extension by default.

Comment: yes it is something like a web app to edit source. Is there any way to achieve it ?